# Excel Find keyword from clipboard (Loop until not found)

Tags: excel, autohotkey

Hi AHKer im a newbie here, i use this to find text from clipboard in Excel, if keyword find in Column.B, copy specific cells, then loop until not found, but however Not working...at all, could someone do me a favor? how to make it work ? thanks!

```
#SingleInstance force Ignore off
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0

IfWinExist, ahk_class Progman
    WinActivate
Sleep 100
PostMessage, 0x50, 0x0804,0,, A
clipboard =
Sleep 300
IfWinExist, huasheng
    WinActivate
Sleep 500
KeyWait, LButton, D
Sleep 1000
Click 3
Send, ^c
ClipWait
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
var := clipboard
var := SubStr(var, InStr(var, "%A_Space%") + 1, InStr(var, "(") - InStr(var, "):") - 3)
Clipboard := var
Xl := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
Xl.Visible := True
Xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
wbk := Xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\iViLL\Google Drive\Doc\ExportOrderList201606161859.Xlsx")
t := %Clipboard%, found := false
x := Xl.Range("B:B").Find(t).row
for Sheet, in wbk.Sheets
{
    if (!c := x)
        continue
    if (!found)
    found := true
    first := c.Value
    Loop
    {
Xl.Range("A" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
MyVar1 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("B" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
MyVar2 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("J" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
MyVar3 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("K" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %A_Space%,, all
MyVar4 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("H" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
MyVar5 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("M" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
MyVar6 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("N" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
MyVar9 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("U" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %A_Space%,, all
MyVar7 :=Clipboard
Xl.Range("AA" x).Copy
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `n,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, all
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %A_Space%,, all
MyVar8 :=Clipboard
IfWinExist Untitled - Notepad
{
WinActivate
WinWaitActive Untitled - Notepad
}
else
IfWinNotExist Untitled - Notepad
{
run, C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
WinWaitActive Untitled - Notepad
}
Sleep 1000
SendRaw ID：%MyVar2%`nNum：%MyVar1%`nStatus：%MyVar5%`nAddress：%MyVar3%，%MyVar6%，%MyVar9%，%MyVar4%
If (MyVar8)
{
IfInString, MyVar7, New Address
{
SendRaw `n%MyVar7%
}
else
IfNotInString, MyVar7, New Address
{
SendRaw `nNew Address：%MyVar3%，%MyVar6%，%MyVar9%，%MyVar8%
}
}
else
{
Sleep 100
}
Sleep 500
Send, ^a
Sleep 100
Send, ^c
Sleep 100
Send, {Delete}
Sleep 300
Winclose, Untitled - Notepad
IfWinExist, huasheng
WinActivate
WinWaitActive huasheng
Send, ^v
    c :=   Sheet.Range("B:B").FindNext(c)
} Until (c.Value = first)
}
if (!found)
msgbox not found!
Return
```

Comment: shrink your code down to the very part where the code doesn't work (use `msgbox` for debugging) and then someone could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use excel's own function "Match" in order to achive your task. I done this kind of thing before and here is example it loop' deletes the row that contains specific text or value,

```
xl := ComObjGet(newestFile)
zeros := xl.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xl.Sheets("Detail").Range("x:x"), "0")

Loop, %zeros%{
zeros := xl.Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH("0", xl.Sheets("Detail").Range("x:x"), 0)
xl.Sheets("Detail").Range(xl.Sheets("Detail").Cells(zeros,4).address,xl.Sheets("Detail").Cells(zeros,6).address).EntireRow.Delete
}
```